# How can we split the string with dilimeter to two columns on spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

> Hi all, in the code below the variable 'name' is eg.
> Firstname,Lastname and we want First name in column b and last name in
> column c
> Hi all, in the code below the variable 'name' is eg.
> Firstname,Lastname and we want First name in column b and last name in
> column c

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1D_oE-3VRWNFG8ZN_gq2KZpx0sJOxwVZ08SLTIByTZ8k');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var timezone = "asia/qatar";
var hours = 3 ;



//MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
function doGet(e){

  Logger.log( JSON.stringify(e) );
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //write_google_sheet() function in esp32 sketch, is send data to this code block
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //get gps data from ESP32
  if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Received data is undefined");
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  var Curr_Date =new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + hours));
  var Curr_Time = Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, timezone, 'HH:mm:ss');
  var name = stripQuotes(e.parameters.name);
  Logger.log('name=' + name);
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  sheet.getRange("A" + nextRow).setValue(Curr_Date);
  sheet.getRange("B" + nextRow).setValue(name);
  sheet.getRange("D" + nextRow).setValue(Curr_Time);
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //returns response back to ESP32
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Card holder name is stored in column B");
  
  }



//MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
function stripQuotes( value ) {
  return value.toString().replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}

//MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
//Extra Function. Not used in this project.
//planning to use in future projects.
//this function is used to handle POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var val = e.parameter.value;
  
  if (e.parameter.value !== undefined){
    var range = sheet.getRange('A2');
    range.setValue(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Hello, We tried using this code                                                                                    
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange('B1:B' + lastRow);
  range.splitTextToColumns(',');                                                                                                            Below the code for the columns A, B and D. However, this splits the whole column and we just want the last cell of B to be split.

Comment: We also tried using var range = sheet.getRange("B" + lastRow); instead of the 2nd line to try and get one cell but this did not work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to split the name in 1 row.  Pay attention to this line of code `name = [Curr_Date].concat(name.split(','),Curr_Time);`

```
function test() {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let timezone = "asia/qatar";
    let hours = 3;
    let Curr_Date = new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + hours));
    let Curr_Time = Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, timezone, 'HH:mm:ss');
    let name = "Tom,Smith";
    name = [Curr_Date].concat(name.split(','),Curr_Time);
    console.log(name);
    let nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    sheet.getRange(nextRow,1,1,name.length).setValues([name]);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
8:42:32 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:42:33 AM  Info    [ Sun Aug 07 2022 11:42:33 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time),
  'Tom',
  'Smith',
  '18:42:33' ]
```

Reference

- [Array.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)